# How to configure automatic Table to IEnumerable<T> parameter conversion in SpecFlow?

Tags: c#, specflow

I have a lot of code that looks like this:

```
[Given(@"user amortizes the deductions:")]
public void GivenUserAmortizesTheDeductions(Table table) {
    var tableRows = table.CreateSet<MyTableRow>();
}
```

It is repetative. I know I can create a `[StepArgumentTransformation]` to convert `Table` to `IEnumerable<MyTableRow>`, but it feels also too repetitive.

**Question:** Is there a way to configure SpecFlow to convert table to IEnumerable automatically without having to explicitly define this relationship every time?

To clarify, every time I add a new step that accepts yet another type of a row, I have to create a corresponding step transformation to support converting it into IEnumerable, i.e.:

```
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public static IEnumerable<FooRow> FooTable(Table table) {
        return table.CreateSet<FooRow>();
    }

    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public static IEnumerable<BarRow> BarTable(Table table) {
        return table.CreateSet<BarRow>();
    }
```

I would like to say this thing once:

```
EnableGlobalSupportForConvertingATableToIEnumerableOfT();
```

Comment: How does a step transformation feel repetitive? Do you want a general-purpose transformer for any type T in `CreateSet<T>`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, yes sir. I've updated my question. I do want to have Table->IEnumerable<T> transformation to work for any T. Just the way string->Enum is OOB.

Comment: I wonder if you could use `[StepArgumentTransformation]` along with `public static IEnumerable CreateSetFromTable(Table table)` and mix in a little class reflection magic.

Comment: Basically, if the step transformation just returns `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: I feel like class reflection should be able to handle this, but I'm not sure how you would get it to play nicely with SpecFlow.

Comment: @GregBurghardt I could use IEnumerable, but I'd have to downcast it, at that point I might just call `table.CreateSet<T>()`. SpecFlow uses TypeDescriptor to execute conversion, but I didn't find (didn't try hard) a simple way to provide a global type extender - but that would be my next SO question.